# Submit records for approval in bulk without hitting DML Statement limit

Tags: limits, governorlimits, approval-process, dml, bulkification

I've got code to create and submit for approval a custom object.
I'm running into the DML statement limit.

As far as I can see each record I submit for approval takes up a DML statement, but there's no option to submit in bulk.......

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can submit multiple Records for approval, sample code below.

```
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> ();
     for (Id oppId: opportunities) {
                    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                    req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval ');
                    req1.setObjectId(oppId);
                    requests.add(req1);
        }


      Approval.ProcessResult[] processResults = null;
                try {
                    processResults = Approval.process(requests, true)
    }catch (System.DmlException e) {
        System.debug('Exception Is ' + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @techtrekker! Couldn't see this in the docs.

Just a note that you need to create the variable requests, something like: 
list<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requests = new list<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

Comment: Absolutely, missed writing the declaration.

Comment: perhaps you could update your answer ;)

Comment: My thoughts exactly.... done ! :)